# Issue in Data class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I created a data class like shown in the pic . I created an object by passing appropriate parameters and I  created another object , simultaneously assigning it to the first object. Later I changed my former object's parameters and checked weather these two objects are equal or not . To my surprise , the Boolean value came "TRUE" but isn't it that the parameters of two objects are different and it should return "FALSE" ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`user2 = user1` means "make `user2` point at the same instance as what `user1` is pointing at". So `user2` and `user1` are referencing the same instance.

If you want `user2` to reference a distinct instance, you can create a copy for it:

```
val user2 = user1.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks sir , got it